# Query is working in phpmyadmin does not work in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this query which gives me what I use it in phpmydmin but in c# it gives the error showed in this [picture](http://www.turcguide.com/stack/union.jpg)

```
SELECT SUM(IF(status=0,montant,0)) AS a_tot, 
SUM(IF(status=0, montant * (tvaval/100),0)) AS a_tva, 
SUM(IF(status= 1, montant,0)) AS v_tot, 
SUM(IF(status=1, montant * (tvaval/100),0)) AS v_tva 
FROM StockData 
UNION ALL 
SELECT SUM(at.prix*at.pax) AS at_tot, 
SUM(at.prix) AS at_prix,SUM(at.pax) AS at_pax, 
SUM(at.vente) AS at_vente FROM Atelier AS at
```

What can be the reason ?

Using c# 2008 MySql 5.0

Comment: I'am expecting each alias with it's own value. But in c# it return with sum on the column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a [UNION ALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

`at_tot` results are being appended to `a_tot`.
`at_prix` results are being appended to `a_tva`.
`at_pax` results are being appended to `v_tot`.
`at_vente` results are being appended to `v_tva`.

The [SQL UNION ALL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) query allows you to combine the result sets of 2 or more SELECT statements. It returns *all rows* from the query (even if the row exists in more than one of the SELECT statements.).  So rows are appended, NOT columns.

EDIT:

Now based on your comments, its simply that you are writing your code as though 8 columns are going to be returned, but you are only getting 4 columns, with 2 rows.

This would work, though returning different data for each row is not recommended.

```
var i = 0;
while (reader.Read())
{
    if(i == 0){
        MyArray[0] = reader["a_tot"].ToString();
        MyArray[1] = reader["a_tva"].ToString();
        MyArray[2] = reader["v_tot"].ToString();
        MyArray[3] = reader["v_tva"].ToString();
        i++;
        }
    else{
        MyArray[0] = reader["at_tot"].ToString();
        MyArray[1] = reader["at_prix"].ToString();
        MyArray[2] = reader["at_pax"].ToString();
        MyArray[3] = reader["at_vente"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.turcguide.com/stack/union1.jpg 
Here there the result is given in two rows I was expecting to get the same result within c# in someway. As I see the mysql interface for c# does not do it.Is there a way to get this sums in one query or I have to do it separately ?

Comment: @IsmailGunes I see, so you are expecting 2 rows with 4 columns?

Comment: @IsmailGunes Check my edit. Given your sql query, this code would work.

Comment: I did it same way I made an 2 dimensional array and with an index I control it


     MyArray[index,0] = reader["v_tot"].ToString();

     MyArray[index,1] = reader["v_tva"].ToString();

     MyArray[index,2] = reader["a_tot"].ToString();

     MyArray[index,3] = reader["a_tva"].ToString();
     ++index;

Comment: @IsmailGunes Upvotes and answers are the way to say thanks :)

Comment: Thanks very much. I got a trouble with my car. So I forgot everything

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42360/discussion-between-ismail-gunes-and-paqogomez)

Answer (score 0):

When you use UNION , the alias that end up in the result are the one from the first select in the union. So `at_tot` (from second select of union) is replaced with a_tot.

What you do is the same as doing:

```sql
SELECT SUM(IF(status=0,montant,0)) AS a_tot, 
       SUM(IF(status=0, montant * (tvaval/100),0)) AS a_tva, 
       SUM(IF(status= 1, montant,0)) AS v_tot, 
       SUM(IF(status=1, montant * (tvaval/100),0)) AS v_tva 
FROM StockData 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
       SUM(at.prix*at.pax), 
       SUM(at.prix),
       SUM(at.pax), 
       SUM(at.vente) 
FROM Atelier AS at
```

You have to put the alias you want in the output in the first select, as you will end up with only 4 columns, not 8 like you are trying to get in your picture.

Comment: I need 8 results from your comment I understand that it's not possible by this way.

Comment: I have to do it with an two dimensionnal array because the reader reads 2 times in first pass it reads the first table in second the second table and control it by an index of this array :((((

Comment: With UNIOn, you are putting the columns from the second select below the ones from the first select. You can however get two rows and put the first row in one place and the second row in the second, but even for that, you would have to add an extra column to the selects to identify them, since the results from an UNION are not guaranteed to be in the same order as you select them.